# How to import and use .jar file on React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, sdk

I am new to React Native. I have this .jar file that contains a function to print on device. The SDK was provided by the supplier of the android device that has an integrated printer on it.

Is it possible to import the .jar file on my project and use the functions on it?

Comment: Anything? I'm interested on answers about it.